# chosen.js Multiple Select, Populate chosen drop down using php array

Tags: php, database, jquery-chosen

ive been using chose for a project and have one last obsticle to over come, chosen works just fine and have ben able to implode the array returned using the following...

```
<select name="uassociations[]" data-placeholder="Choose Associations"   value="$associations" class="chzn-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
```

and extracted the returned array using...

```
$imp_associations = implode(",", $associations);
```

but i want to populate the chosen multiple select from the database which is seperate using commas, i can epxlode the string but cant get it to populate the chosen box :(

can any one shed any light on this for me as its really not documented that well

tried the following..

```
$imp_associations = implode(",", $associations);
```

and tried adding the this in the html

```
value="$associations
```

any help or direction would be brill ;)